# My list response to css only when Im using li

Tags: css

I'm making a lottery display. I'm trying to style my list that shows the "winning numbers" but the style applies only when I'm using `li` on CSS. I tried using `div` to all `li` or giving a class to all `li`'s - not working...

```css
.draw_numbers {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  background: #666;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 127.4%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class="draw_numbers">
    <li class="number main"></li>
    <li class="number main"></li>
    <li class="number main"></li>
    <li class="number main"></li>
    <li class="number main"></li>
    <li class="number main"></li>
    <li style="background: red !important;" class="number special">
      <div class="tag" aria-hidden="true">BB</div>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to add a `.` before `draw_numbers` in the style element: `<style> .draw_numbers{`. Eplanation: the `.` means that you are targeting a *class name*.

Comment: Your mark up is invalid. *Permitted parents An <ul>, <ol>, or <menu> element. Though not a conforming usage, the obsolete <dir> can also be a parent.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Comment: @Dor_k Please take note of the edits I made on your post for proper formatting on future questions.

Comment: What exactly doesnt work? It works when I try it with your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not have a div as a child of a ul. You are applying the css to the wrong element.

```css
.draw_numbers li {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  background: #666;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 127.4%;
}

.draw_numbers li.special {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="draw_numbers">
  <li class="number main"></li>
  <li class="number main"></li>
  <li class="number main"></li>
  <li class="number main"></li>
  <li class="number main"></li>
  <li class="number main"></li>
  <li class="number special">
    <div class="tag" aria-hidden="true">BB</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

They won't be integrated because you need to specify that `draw_numbers` is a class, just a little tiny dot seems like enough to do the work in your style tag.

Comment: I dont know why this hasnt show the `.` but I have one. dont know what to do:(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to act directly on the class you have assigned to your li?
.numbers or .main
You can also try assigning the class .draw_number to your ul tag:
.draw_number .li {
...
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).